# Haskell - intersperse a parser with another one

Tags: parsing, haskell, megaparsec

I have two parsers `parser1 :: Parser a` and `parser2 :: Parser a`.

I would like now to parse a list of `a`s interspersing them with `parser2`

The desired signature is something like

```
interspersedParser :: Parser b -> Parser a -> Parser [a]
```

For example, if `Parser a` parses the `'a'` character and `Parser b` parser the `'b'` character, then the `interspersedParser` should parse

```
""
"a"
"aba"
"ababa"
...
```

I'm using megaparsec. Is there already some combinator which behaves like this, which I'm currently not able to find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In parsec there is a `sepBy` parser which does that. The same parser seems to be available in megaparsec as well: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-4.4.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec-Combinator.html

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can use `sepBy`, but isn't this just:

```
interspersedParser sepP thingP = (:) <$> thingP <*> many (sepP *> thingP)
```

EDIT: Oh, this requires at least one thing to be there. You also wanted empty, so just stick a `<|> pure []` on the end.

In fact, this is basically how `sepBy1` (a variant of `sepBy` that requires at least one) is implemented:

```
-- | @sepBy p sep@ parses /zero/ or more occurrences of @p@, separated
-- by @sep@. Returns a list of values returned by @p@.
--
-- > commaSep p = p `sepBy` comma

sepBy :: Alternative m => m a -> m sep -> m [a]
sepBy p sep = sepBy1 p sep <|> pure []
{-# INLINE sepBy #-}

-- | @sepBy1 p sep@ parses /one/ or more occurrences of @p@, separated
-- by @sep@. Returns a list of values returned by @p@.

sepBy1 :: Alternative m => m a -> m sep -> m [a]
sepBy1 p sep = (:) <$> p <*> many (sep *> p)
{-# INLINE sepBy1 #-}
```